# (Retrofit) Could not locate converter for class crashing app

Tags: java, android, retrofit

So Retrofit 2.0.0 was recently released and theres not really any updated examples on how to use it, but im trying to implement it for a basic API call. Im getting a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class`
```

caused by

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate converter for class orbyt.app.dataclass. Tried:
* retrofit.OkHttpBodyConverterFactory
```

When trying to make the api call.

Comment: not know Retrofit, I guess there is a annotation who can specify the converter somewhere.

Comment: @JiangYD not sure what you mean

Comment: you need to post more code about this error. Post you api call.

Comment: The example on http://square.github.io/retrofit/ throws this error. Try it if you don't believe the person asking the question, or if you want details. They aren't trying to do anything fancy.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. I fixed it by adding :

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:<latest-version>'
```

to my build.gradle

Then specify the converter when creating my Retrofit instance.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: So i fixed this last night actually by basically copying [these](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson/src/main/java/retrofit) 2 classes into my project and calling the `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`. Linking the converters via gradle is obviously a cleaner option, so marking this as the answer.

Comment: Also make sure that your version for `converter-gson` matches your version for `retrofit` itself - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902157/retrofit-convertor-factory-can-not-access-gsonconverterfactory

Comment: This answer is out of date, Gradle won't even sync with this version, much less compile. You need compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'

Answer (score 18):

In Retrofit 2.0, Converter is not included in the package and 
when you are using Retrofit 2.0 Make Sure follow new URL pattern

**Base URL: always ends with /**

**@Url: DO NOT start with /**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

For more information about 2.0 Follow this link [Retrofit 2.0: The biggest update](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en)

And also update build.gradle.

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
```

And add the extension in project level build.gradle file

```
ext {
retrofit_version= "2.x.x"
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't include the relevant Gradle dependency.

Comment: @Ak I have mention best biggest update link they have mentioned all this things. Need to update API basis on current version

Answer (score 7):

Change retrofit version accordingly

For me below dependency was there already

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
```

For gson 2.0.2 I changed

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

Then add

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: This answer is up to date, it should have more votes than the outdated one and more than the one that doesn't even include the relevant dependency.

Answer (score 6):

For Retrofit V2 add the following repositories -

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
```

Now use below code -

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 3):

In the latest Retrofit 2.0,you should import the latest version :

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0'
```

Be careful call `baseUrl()`，at v2.0,it should be end of "/",and at the method ,you would’t start thr url with"/"

```
@POST("classes/info")
Call<ContactBean> insertInfo(@Body ContactBean bean);
```

And you can see [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to get more info!
Hope help !

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's old question. But I've faced the same problem. And no one answer suits to me.
According to the [documentation](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters#retrofit-converters), it ships with support for OkHttp's *RequestBody* and *ResponseBody* types.
So no need to include `.addConverterFactory(AnyFactory.create()`) in your builder. There is an opportunity works with raw type of a response. All you need is to return `Response<ResponseBody>` or `Call<ResponseBody>` or `Single<Response<ResponseBody>>` from an interface of api.

Comment: if you didn't add addConverterFactory retrofit response always in ResponseBody. And if you add addConverterFactory( gson or other ) then you must provide model class in response. ConverterFactory is convert json or your date in to model so model must needed

Answer (score 1):

In [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974908/how-to-download-pdf-file-with-retrofit-and-kotlin-coroutines/57052410) (Kotlin with coroutines) I received the exception:

> Unable to create converter for retrofit2.Call
>
> for method Queries.exportPdf.
>
> Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ResponseBody
>   converter for retrofit2.Call

A problem was in a request:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Streaming
@POST("export-pdf/")
suspend fun exportPdf(
    @Field("token") token: String
): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Removed `suspend` from definition and exceptions disappeared.