# retrofit convertor factory can not access GsonConverterFactory

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I have included these dependencies to my project:

> compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
>   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'

I have a class where I am going to access my api's via retrofit:

```
 public static  <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String baseUrl) {


        Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();    

            RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();*/

        return  builder.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

And now, it gives me this compile time error :

> Error:(24, 17) error: method addConverterFactory in class Builder
>   cannot be applied to given types; required: Factory found:
>   GsonConverterFactory reason: actual argument GsonConverterFactory
>   cannot be converted to Factory by method invocation conversion

How can I solve this? I followed the documentation. What is wrong?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Try to use same version for retrofit and converter-gson - `2.0.0-beta2`. You are using `beta2` for retrofit and `beta1` for converter.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

**Important note!**

Retrofit change its package name since `2.0.0-beta3` version. Now you should use `com.squareup.retrofit2`. Here is example:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

Comment: you are a big man). But there is no any resource that indicates i must use same beta2 version.

Comment: @AEMLoviji The resource is called common sense, wouldn't you agree? Most notably because during beta phase interfaces are subject to change which IS written in the retrofit docs.

Comment: I just ran into this problem. and she resolved 2 hours back. thank!)

Comment: Please consider updating the answer since as of Beta 2.0.3 the packagename isn't `com.squareup.retrofit` anymore but `com.squareup.retrofit2` instead.

Answer (score 11):

In `build.gradle` (app) instead of:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

write:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

With latest Beta 2.0.3 release you need to add :

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
```

Make sure to match the retrofit library version with gson converter version.

Comment: The difference is hard to spot. So for everyone who's as blind as I am - you need to add `2` to the package name.

Answer (score 3):

This is the latest:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0'
```

If you use beta version:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  error: method addConverterFactory in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
    required: Factory
    found: GsonConverterFactory
    reason: actual argument GsonConverterFactory cannot be converted to Factory by method invocation conversion
```

If you are getting this error, The reason is wrong dependancy included.

Add/ change dependency in application `build.gradle`  file as

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'  
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

make sure that converter version is `2.0.0-beta2` not `2.0.0-beta1`.