# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field FCMResponce.success' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, retrofit

how to solve this error

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.ddu.d_ride_customer.Model.FCMResponce.success' on a null object reference`

FCMClient class

```
public class FCMClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static Retrofit getClient(String baseURL)
{
    if(retrofit == null)
    {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
  }
}
```

sample code that generates the error

```
   mService.sendMessage(content)
                                .enqueue(new Callback<FCMResponce>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call<FCMResponce> call, Response<FCMResponce> response) {
                                        if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null) {
                                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Request sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                        else
                                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Gson in .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
So You would also need interface for Retrofit before You return retrofit. You should have interface that parse response. 
So for example gsonInterface (random name) that can use response https://square.github.io/retrofit/ (Example from retrofit GitHub: public interface

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

)
And then before returning retrofit
gsonInterface = retrofit.create(gsonInterafce.class);
Or comment out line .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) 
Also use same version of libs:
[retrofit convertor factory can not access GsonConverterFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902157/retrofit-convertor-factory-can-not-access-gsonconverterfactory)

Comment: Please hide api key from your comment.

Comment: public interface IFCMService { @Headers({ "Content-Type:application/json", "Authorization:Key=AAAAF4ob75Y:APA91bEwOLl6608rdRMsDYyhV8Bd61wxWQYItrrmiinzDu-nUFqlbzdphqmMWahXz6cNLf5lFw44sIG49qWH9N-EHoyB38Hrx88DggodeGTW_RH43OLJOvO_Pg660DDMV6_kGEuSAx" }) @POST("fcm/send") Call<FCMResponse> sendMessage(@Body Sender body); }

Comment: Also problem should be with method IFCMService mService = retrofit.create( IFCMService.class); or instance of it. Code that You pasted in Your original post looks ok. Also could You add Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create(); before retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder() ? It seems to be missing and You use GsonConverterFactory.create() https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-adding-customizing-the-gson-converter

Comment: thanks for replaying back and the error is still not cleared ...may be do you think the problem is with the API key ???

Comment: You can check server response with normal http request (if retrofit should read it You should be also able to check it in browser). This way You can check api key. If it`s working , but error still occurs it can be interface implementation.