# Error: incompatible types: GsonConverterFactory cannot be converted to Factory

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to use Retrofit 2.0.0.beta2, when setting up the Converter for 
Gson like below

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

After this gradle throwing error

> GsonConverterFactory cannot be converted to Factory

How to fix it ???

Comment: I hope you are not added GSON converter in gradle

Comment: Please see this link may be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343183/retrofit-could-not-locate-converter-for-class-crashing-app/32652747#32652747

Answer (score 11):

you are probably the first beta of `GsonConverterFactory` with the 2nd beta of `Retrofit`. Please make sure that you have

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

in your gradle

Comment: Blackbelt; you always show up when needed; thanks from room-15

Comment: I get an error: `addConverterFactory(retrofit2.Converter.Factory) in Builder cannot be applied to (retrofit.GsonConverterFactory)`

Comment: It depends on the version of retrofit you are using. This answer refers to the 2nd beta of retrofi2.

Answer (score 2):

I got the issue...

> I was using  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
>   instead of 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'}
```