# Retrofit usage in with API in Java

Tags: java, github, retrofit, retrofit2, github-api

According to information from official site I added latest depedency and started to develop.

First I created model with data I'm interested:

```
public class Data{
    String parametr1;
    //geters and setters ommited
}
```

second step was to add service:

```
public interface GitHubService {
    @GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}")
    Call<Data> repoInfos(@Path("user") String owner, @Path("repo") String repo);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.github.com/").build();
}
```

Third one was to add implementation:

```
@Service
public class GitHubServiceImpl implements GitHubService {

    final GitHubService gitHubService = GitHubService.retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);

    @Override
    public Call<DetailDto> repoDetails(String owner, String repo) {
        return gitHubService.repoDetails(owner, repo);
    }
}
```

But there is an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ResponseBody converter for class model.Data.
```

[Here is full error log trace](https://pastebin.com/RuG6KCn2)

Comment: Did you checked this out ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343183/retrofit-could-not-locate-converter-for-class-crashing-app

Comment: I'm using maven, not grandle, but maybe it will solve my problem, give me a second to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
    <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
    <version><latest-version></version>
</dependency>
```

For code add a ConverterFactory:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

This should do it.

Comment: I added this depedency, but there is another problem.

Comment: what kind of a problem

Comment: There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
retrofit2.OkHttpCall cannot be cast to model.Data.

Here is a full error trace: https://pastebin.com/5Z36AQ7B.

Comment: server error I can't help sorry. btw try not to comment many times after your self just edit the previous message unless someone else posted after you.

Comment: I changed a return type from Data to Call<Data> and now there is no error, but instead of information I wanted it prints:
 {"canceled":false,"executed":false}.

Ok I'll try to edit previous messages. :)